# Question regarding the distribution of OLS estimators

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear

In linear regression: Why does the sampling distribution of OLS estimators depend on the underlying distribution of errors? Thanks!

(I am relatively new to statistics in general, so more simply worded answers would be appreciated :)!)

Answer (score 5):

Since you want simple answers, let's simplify the situation to the simplest regression model -- an intercept only model (`~1` in R).

Then under least squares the parameter estimate will be the sample mean.

The distribution of the sample mean depends on the distribution of the population the sample was drawn from.

The sample mean is just 1/n times the sum, and for independent continuous (/discrete) variates, the distribution of the sum is the convolution of the pds (/pmfs).

So for example (assuming i.i.d. throughout):

- if the population distribution is exponential$(1/\mu)$ (rate parameterization), the distribution of the sum is gamma$(n,1/\mu)$ (shape-rate parameterization)
- if the population distribution is uniform, the sum of two is triangular and the sum of n of them is [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) (or more generally, a location-scale family based on the Irwin-Hall)
- if the population distribution is Poisson, the sum is Poisson
- if the population distribution is Bernoulli, the sum is binomial
- if the population distribution is normal, the sum is normal

and so on.

With simple or multiple regression the vector of parameters is a linear function of the data:

$$\hat{\beta} = Ay, \quad\text{where }\: A = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$$

and as such will also be different for different conditional distributions for the response $f(Y|\underline{x})$, though we won't have convenient names for most of the distributions of weighted sums or weighted averages.

In sufficiently large samples you may be able to argue that the coefficient estimates will be approximately normal.

Comment: Does this answer implies that the sampling distribution of OLS estimators depend on the underlying distribution of errors and of the the different $X$?

Comment: More than merely "*implies*", I think, and it's not just the answer, for the errors at least, that's the premise of the question. The fact that the answer responds to the question that takes the dependence on the errors as a given without correcting that premise  indicates that the answer agrees with the premise and treats that premise as established fact. The answer goes on to give explicit examples of such dependence (taking it well beyond implication). The answer then indicates that it also depends on the design by demonstrating how it can be seen as a kind of weighted sum dependent on X

Comment: ... Note, however, that it's better in general not to cast it in terms of the distribution of the errors but in terms of the distribution of the conditional response (as the answer does in place of the question's reliance on errors).